# How do I position a control created in UIKit quickly?

Tags: iphone, uikit

Is there a quick way to position a ui control (such as bottom center or top center)? Right now I routinely set the frame of the UIcontrol or UIView subclass to position them but would like to know if I can avoid doing calculation just to centralize a control.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a view's center property to the center property of the parent if you want it centered. That does not set it's width and height though.

Answer (score 0):

No, iPhone OS only supports "Struts and Springs" layout.

But you could easily create category methods that do this for you:

```
- (void)positionAtTopCenterOfSuperView;
- (void)positionAtCenterOfSuperView;
- (void)positionAtBottomCenterOfSuperView;
```

These are pretty trivial to write, but will save you time in the future. In fact I think I might make this category myself.